# How to find the matrix of LFSR output?

Tags: lfsr

I am trying to find polynomial , but don't know how to get matrix
matrix must look something like this:https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/computer-security-and/9780471947837/sec8.8.html
For example if output is 11010110 and length of register was 4, how to get such matrix:
1   1   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   1
0   1   0   1   1
1   0   1   1   0

Comment: http://bma.bozhu.me/

Comment: Can't you read the indexes? Each row has size 4 and there are 4 rows. Insert the first 4 elements into the matrix, then remove the first shift left and add the next item. $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: the row length is register length+1, column length is register length , right?

Comment: It is a square matrix and the column(row) size is equal to the length of the LFSR. `8.8.a The row of the N × N matrix` from your link.

Comment: but in example row length is 5

Comment: Which example? I don't see that. You said the register length is 4! And, $x^4 + x^3 + 1$ from the link of the first comment.

Comment: output was 11010110 and length of register is 4, how to get such matrix: 
1 1 0 1 0 /
1 0 1 0 1 /
0 1 0 1 1 /
1 0 1 1 0 /
You see, each row is 5 bit

Comment: Why do you insist on constructing the size 5 matrix? In your case, it is a  $4\times 4$ matrix. Can't you read it from your link? I fear that your next question will be how to use this matrix!

Comment: I think link shows another thing.  I must do like this example and trying to find size of matrix.